# Sensores en Android. No consiguo que se muestren

Tags: android, sensor

Tengo un programa en el que debo mostrar en unos textview la información de los sensores que se obtiene del dispositivo, pero no se muestran.

**Este es mi código:**

```
private ListView miListView;
private SensorManager miSensorManager;
private Sensor miSensor;
private TextView miTextView;
private TextView miTextLuz;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensores);
    miSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    miSensor = miSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    miTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    miTextLuz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLuz);

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
      switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT:
          if (sensorEvent.values[0] == 0.0) {
            miTextLuz.setText("No veo nada!!!");
          } else {
            miTextLuz.setText("Parece que hay buena iluminación");
          }
        case Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY:
          miTextView.setText(String.valueOf(sensorEvent.values[0]));
          if (sensorEvent.values[0] == 0.0) {
            textView.setText("Demasiado cerca");
          }
          break;
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    // Paramos el acceso a los sensores cuando no sea necesario.
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      miSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
```

---

**Actualización de código:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensores);
    miSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    miSensorLuz = miSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    miSensorProx = miSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
    miTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    miTextLuz = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLuz);
    if (miSensorLuz != null) {
      miSensorManager.registerListener(this, miSensorLuz, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    } else {
      Log.d("SENSOR", "NOT Available");
    }

    if (miSensorProx != null) {
      miSensorManager.registerListener(this, miSensorProx, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    } else {
      Log.d("SENSOR", "NOT Available");
    }
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
      switch (sensorEvent.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT:
          if (sensorEvent.values[0] == 0.0) {
            miTextLuz.setText("No veo nada!!!");
          } else {
            miTextLuz.setText("Parece que hay buena iluminación");
          }
        case Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY:
          miTextView.setText(String.valueOf(sensorEvent.values[0]));
          if (sensorEvent.values[0] == 0.0) {
            textView.setText("Demasiado cerca");
          }
          break;
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

    }

    // Paramos el acceso a los sensores cuando no sea necesario.
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      miSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: textView.setText("Demasiado cerca"); ??? debe ser miTextView.setText("Demasiado cerca");

Answer (score 1):

No veo que registres el `Listener`, debes realizarlo para que se registren los cambios en  `onSensorChanged()`

```
  miSensorManager.registerListener(
                    this,
                    miSensor,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

De esta forma lo realizas dentro de `onCreate()`:

```
SensorManager miSensorManager;
Sensor mySensorProximity;
Sensor mySensorLight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sensores);
    miSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    mySensorLight = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    mySensorProximity = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);
 ...
 ...

   if(mySensorLight != null){
        Log.d(TAG, " existe TYPE_LIGHT : " + mySensorLight.getName());
        mySensorManager.registerListener(
                this,
                mySensorLight,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT NOT Available");
    }

    if(mySensorProximity != null){
        Log.d(TAG, " existe TYPE_PROXIMITY : " + mySensorProximity.getName());
        mySensorManager.registerListener(
                this,
                mySensorProximity,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    }else{
        Log.d(TAG, "Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY NOT Available");
    }



}
```

Comment: Buenas. Ahora sí me va, pero tengo otro problema y es que solo recoge los datos del sensor de luz, del otro sensor no recoge información ya que el textview no cambia. He probado poniendo un synchrinized, pero tampoco, ¿sabrías por qué pasa esto? Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @PacoPepe Debes registrar un listener para el otro sensor, revisa la actualización.

Comment: Hola. Lo he escrito tal y como aparece, pero me sigue cogiendo la información del sensor de luz nada más. He probado a cambiar el orden de los case en el switch del onSensorChanged y pasa lo mismo; solo me registra el sensor de luz. Gracias.

Comment: tienes definido : miSensor = miSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT); que ya no es necesario, ahora debes definir :         mySensorLight = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);  y también
        mySensorProximity = mySensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

Comment: Revisa en el LogCat que no despliegue  "NOT Available" puede ser que tu dispositivo no tenga sensor de proximidad. Asegura que la actualización de código sea la que tienes en tu proyecto.

Comment: No me salen en el log. Mi móvil dispone de esos sensores. Y he actualizado el código.

Comment: ok, en cuanto a el sensor de proximidad tienes : if (sensorEvent.values[0] == 0.0) {
es dificil que ambos sensores puedan llegar a cero , agrega que muestre un texto si es diferente a 0.0 y veras que funciona.

Comment: El de luz sí llega a 0, solamente tapando con el dedo el sensor de luz me cambia el mensaje, pero el de proximidad por mucho que tape el móvil no hace nada.